# Postgres: Unable to connect to server. role 'postgres' does not exist

Tags: postgresql, pg

I am new to PostgreSQL and I just have installed pg4admin. I have found out that there are no servers, so I tried to create one, but end up with error shown on the attached screenshot.

By the way, I am able to:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
psql
\du
```

and see:

```
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

[image]

I will appreciate any help related to the solution regarding creating PostgreSQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if only one of the things that I did helped or both are required, but here is what I have done:

- changed port to 5433 (this seems to be something for sure needed, but I have tried this before with no luck)
- I created a new role and a new OS user with the same name as the role.

With this two it worked for me.